# How can I put every sentence of a text in a row of a table next to its translation in a Google Document?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, nlp, translation, google-docs

I want to put a text to be translated in a Google Doc so that every sentence is in its own row of a table. In each row of the next column is the corresponding, machine-translated sentence. Finally, there is a third blank column where I will write my own translation for each sentence.

[Like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f07Dj.png)

What would some command line code look like for accessing the specific Google Doc, inserting a table, splitting the text on each sentence, and then writing each sentence to a row of the table?

I am aware of Google API, but I have struggled with authentication problems so far. If someone can sketch out a general outline of what my script should look like, hopefully I can fill in the details.

I am trying my best to meet Stack Overflow's post guidelines, so if the question is not a good one, I'm happy to reformulate it. My question is multi-part, so I prefer to ask the broader version first, before breaking it into smaller aspects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
function translate() {
  var doc = DocumentApp.openById('documentID');
  var body = doc.getBody();
  var str = "An elephant is the biggest living animal on land. It is quite huge in size. It is usually black or grey in colour. Elephants have four legs, a long trunk and two white tusks near their trunk. Apart from this, they have two big ears and a short tail. Elephants are vegetarian. They eat all kinds of plants especially bananas. They are quite social, intelligent and useful animals. They are used to carry logs of wood from one place to another. They are good swimmers.";
  //Split paragraph into sentences.
  var result = str.match( /[^\.!\?]+[\.!\?]+/g ).map(str => str.trim());;
  var translated = [];
  result.forEach(res => {
    translated.push(LanguageApp.translate(res, 'en', 'es'));
  })

  var table = body.appendTable();
  for(var i = 0; i <= result.length; i++){
    var tr = table.appendTableRow();
    if(i == 0){
      tr.appendTableCell("Origin");
      tr.appendTableCell("Translated");
      tr.appendTableCell("");
    }else{
      tr.appendTableCell(result[i-1]);
      tr.appendTableCell(translated[i-1]);
      tr.appendTableCell("");
    }
  }
}
```

**Output:**

[image: output]

### References:

- [translate(text, sourceLanguage, targetLanguage)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/language/language-app#translatetext,-sourcelanguage,-targetlanguage)
- [appendTableRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/table#appendtablerow)
- [appendTableCell()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/table-row#appendtablecell)

Comment: Thanks very much. Is this meant to be run from within Google Docs or from the command line? What command do you invoke to execute the script, i.e., python? Thanks very much for your help

Comment: The code is for [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview). In your Google Documents: Go to Tools -> Script editor

Comment: Here is an example of python script using Google Docs API. [link](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/quickstart/python)

Comment: Thanks so much - I really appreciate it.

Comment: How about a Google Apps Script to make a table in Google Docs so that every sentence of a text is in a row of a table, like this:

Table:

Sentence 1
Sentence 2
Sentence 3
Etc.

Thank you so much.